# lost .keystore file but I know the password

Tags: android, keystore

I developed some time ago an android app, but unfortunately I lost the .keystore file, but I know the password of the keystore.

If I generate a new .keystore with same password I will able to update my application?

If not, do I have any chance to recover after I reinstalled windows a couple of times?

Answer (score 2):

> If I generate a new .keystore with same password I will able to update my application?

No.

> If not, do I have any chance to recover after I reinstalled windows a couple of times?

Probably not, but that would be a far better question for some site dedicated to Windows PC maintenance.

It would be far simpler for you to just restore your keystore from the backup you made of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CommonsWare's answer:

Keystore files are usually very small (less than 4KB) therefore you have a very small chance that the data may still be somewhere if exactly that part has not been overwritten.

From your published app you could extract the used certificate and the use parts of the certificate for a search based on the file-content on your hard disk on raw level (the complete hard-disk as one file).

I don't know if there are tools that can recover/find Android keystore files on raw level. If not a hex editor with the capability to search for hex data may be worth a try.